# Magento Store ID Increment

Tags: php, magento

We have a complex Magento which talks through the API to a stock management system.

The stock management system looks for store ID's to establish the source but is only set up to recognise numbers 1-9 as a store ID which means we have 9 slots available.

We have set up 3 store views then set up then deleted a fourth.

Our problem is, after deleting the 4th, the next store was assigned store ID 5 meaning we have lost one of our 9 slots.

Does anyone know a solution whereby we can assign store IDs, or at least ensure that magento takes up the lowest available ID.

Tricky one, I know but I have faith! :)

Comment: Change the id in the database in `core_store` table. If you have the constraints on the tables it should be updated everywhere. But back-up first.

Comment: I've tried that but it caused errors on the indexing process?

Comment: What were the errors in the indexing process?